# get a small list when clicked on a button

Tags: android, listview

i have a image view and on top of it i have a button. now what i want is when i click on the button i should get a list of images on same Activity.actually i am trying to make a list in button,s onClick event. event gets fired but it does not show the list. anybody can have any idea how shall i achieve this i am also making my layout programmatically.

thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing some code it's hard to give a definite answer, but these are a few possibilities.

Create the listview together with the button, but set it's visibility to `View.GONE` or `View.INVISIBLE`. In the button's `onClick` method, set it to `View.VISIBLE`.

Alternatively, do the listview creation in the button's `onClick` (which I gather is what you're doing?), making sure you don't forget to add it to your layout. I have no idea why this does not work for you. Show some code or use the debugger to step through it and find out where it goes wrong.